# Color-code a Leaflet GeoJSON polyline based on additional values

Tags: leaflet, geojson, color

I almost repeated [Color-code a Leaflet polyline based on additional values, e.g. altitude, speed,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90193) because after more than eight years, I have not found a satisfactory answer.

I need a **gradien** color of a **GeoJSON** LineString object.

The `style` option of `L.GeoJSON` object allows to specify only solid color.
The available extensions allow creating only an `L.Polyline` object with gradient color ([this](https://github.com/iosphere/Leaflet.hotline/) and [this](https://github.com/Oliv/leaflet-polycolor), for example).

But I update my line dynamically in real time, so it should be an `L.GeoJSON` object.

Can anyone suggest an idea or solution how to make a gradient color of the line exactly in a `L.GeoJSON` object?

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code. Add also references to available extensions that allow L.Polyline with gradient color.

Comment: Can you split your single line into segments that each contain a property that you want to colorize?  Then use the example here? - https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: Be careful: there is no problem with solid color. See `style` option of L.GeoJSON object.

Comment: Please edit your question and add code how you define/create your GeoJSON layer and how you update it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Both mentioned projects use an custom L.Renderer for coloring a polyline segments. You can using this renderer (if it is possible) to color the GeoJSON object via the `style` option as follows:

```
var polyline = L.geoJSON(geoJSONdata,{
    style: function(feature){
        return {
            renderer: new L.Renderer.RendererGradient(),
            colors: colorsArray, // options for renderer
            weight: 5 // options for polyline
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Here we use a renderer from  [leaflet-polycolor](https://github.com/Oliv/leaflet-polycolor) that allows do it.

However, I extracted the renderer from [leaflet-polycolor](https://github.com/Oliv/leaflet-polycolor) and put it in a [separate git repo](https://github.com/VladimirKalachikhin/polycolorRenderer) because the size of the renderer alone is almost four times smaller than the entire project.
The comments and samples included.

But it seems to me that using a renderer is an overkill for such task. But there is no other way.